# Why do poisoned catalysts (Lindlar, nickel borate) result in partial hydrogenation of alkynes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrogen, catalysis, chemoselectivity

I read that alkene is more reactive than alkyne, so in hydrogenation of alkynes, it's difficult to isolate the alkenes.

But with poisoned catalysts like Lindlar's catalyst or Nickel-Boron (Ni<sub>2</sub>B), they only catalyze the alkyne-to-alkene reaction, and won't catalyze the alkene-to-alkane reaction.

I'm curious about the reason. Why won't they catalyze the halogenation of alkenes? What is the mechanism?

[image]

Comment: They do; it's just much slower. If you leave a Lindlar on for too long it goes all the way to the alkane. Now as to why it's slower... I found a reference on this before... I'll try to dig it up.

Comment: I don't think the exact mechanism is very well understood; but here are a few references to check: [*Chem. Rev.* **2013,** *113* (3), 1313–1350](https://doi.org/10.1021/cr3001753) — [*J. Org. Chem.* **1983,** *48* (23), 4436–4438](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00171a069) — [*Theor. Chem. Acc.* **2011,** *128* (4-6), 663–673](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00214-010-0800-0) — [*J. Mol. Catal. A* **2001,** *173* (1-2), 185–221](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1381-1169(01)00150-9). Sorry, I'm really not sure how helpful this is, but it's what I have.

Comment: I suspect the answer can be found in this book chapter from Comprehensive Organic Named Reactions but it is behind a paywall  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470638859.conrr395  A key sentence from the abstract gives a clue "The addition of lead acetate has been suggested to block the most active catalyst sites and prevent overreduction of alkenes to alkanes."